# Removing Duplicates with Awk

Tags: awk

I have 2 files new.csv & remove.txt.  I'm using AWK to use a master remove file from any new csv files that are generated.  The files are:

```
$ cat new.csv 

james,smith,bronx,2025555551
adam,stephenson,brooklyn,2025555552
anthony,jackson,queens,2025555553
mary,young,astoria,2025555554
marsha,peterson,madison,2025555555
angie,huff,belk,2025555556
```

Then there is:

```
$ cat remove.txt 

2025555550
2025555553
2025555555
2025555557
2025555558
2025555559
```

My command is:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{remove[$4]++;next}!($4 in remove)' remove.txt new.csv > final.csv
```

This gives me the same as the original, like this:

```
$ cat final.csv 

james,smith,bronx,2025555551
adam,stephenson,brooklyn,2025555552
anthony,jackson,queens,2025555553
mary,young,astoria,2025555554
marsha,peterson,madison,2025555555
angie,huff,belk,2025555556
```

How do I get this?

```
$ cat final.csv 

james,smith,bronx,2025555551
adam,stephenson,brooklyn,2025555552
mary,young,astoria,2025555554
angie,huff,belk,2025555556
```

Comment: The column to remove isn't `$4` in `remove.txt` you need `remove[$1]++`.

Comment: @Etan Reisner - this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!  So, for anyone who runs across this it is `$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{remove[$1]++;next}!($4 in remove)' remove.txt new.csv > final.csv` .

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior You should post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[Etan Reisner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) solution:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{remove[$1]++;next}!($4 in remove)' remove.txt new.csv
```

This works very well.

For anyone less knowledgeable about AWK, a more elaborate and programmatic solution is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while((getline var < "remove.txt")>0) {remove[var]=0}; FS=","}
     {if(!($4 in remove)) {print $0}}' new.csv
```

The BEGIN block run before starting to read the input file "new.csv" reads the entire key file "remove.txt" into an associative array with keys as the remove keys. It also sets the field separator to "," instead of the default whitespace. The main block which reads the input file one line at a time then checks whether the 4th (last) field is present in any of the remove keys and prints otherwise.